# Magic: the Gathering - Goblin Horde

Tags: calculation-puzzle, magic-the-gathering

**The Challenge**
Using only lands and Goblins, your goal is to build a Magic: the Gathering deck that can win the game as quickly as possible, against an opponent who does nothing. You may assume that your deck is stacked, so that you will always draw exactly the cards you want.

**Scoring**
The winning answer will be the one which can defeat the opponent in as few turns as possible. You may choose to play or draw, but winning on the play is considered faster than winning on the draw.
In the event that two solutions are equally fast, the winner will be the solution that deals more damage.
In the event that two solutions are equally fast and equally damaging, the winner will be the one that uses less cards.

**Possibly Asked Questions**
When you say Goblins...
Any card with the subtype Goblin. So no [Goblin Game](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=8902) or [Dragon Fodder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398647).

What's the opponent doing?
The opponent's deck consists of sixty islands, and they begin the game by mulliganing to zero. They will take no game actions unless an effect requires them to.

Loopholes?
Your solution may not rely upon random chance such as winning coinflips, or the opponent doing something suicidal, like choosing 20 on [Choice of Damnations](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=88803)

Comment: I'm curious - was your infinite combo one of mine, or something else entirely?

Comment: I found almost exactly your pre-combat combo, only I didn't use Frogtosser so it went T1 Mountain, Prospector, T2 Ancient Tomb, War Marshal, Warleader - etc.

Comment: The T1.5 kill of: Gemstone (exile any) > Tomb > Akki > Skirk > Sac Akki > Mogg > Sac Mogg > Lackey > Kicked Bushwhacker > attack, put Ringleader in play > Sac Lackey, Bushwhacker, Ringleader > Mogg > Sac Mogg > Warchief > Mogg > Sac Mogg > Ringleader > Sac Ringleader > Mogg > Sac Mogg > Krenko, tap for 3 > Sac Krenko and 2 > Krenko, tap for 4 > Sac Krenko and 5 > Ringleader > Krenko, tap for 4 > sac Krenko and 2 > Krenko, tap for 6 > Sac Krenko and 6 > Kiki-Jiki > Lightning Crafter > Victory... is exactly one card off, which makes me very sad (you'd need an opening hand of 8 cards somehow).

Comment: @Zerris I can get a little further than that but I"m still stuck spinning my wheels. Gemstone (any), Tomb, Akki, Skirk, Mogg, Mogg, Ringleader, Mons's Goblin Waiters and I'm left with RR, Prospector, 3 cards in hand. Can't go mana positive before running out of cards. It's so close, this is going to drive me crazy.

Comment: Mons' isn't legal, though, unless we want to allow some truly broken things.

Comment: @Zerris Hey, the Waiters are goblins aren't they? Under the restriction of "Lands and goblins", I don't think there's anything special we can do with the Un sets, the only relevant cards are the Waiters and City of Ass. I suppose T1 City, Prospector, T2 City, Frogtosser, Mogg slightly imrpoves the T2 precombat solution, and "No Un cards" is generally a good rule, but was there something particularly broken you were thinking of?

Comment: Well, in that case, I make a deck consisting of 60 Mountains.  Then, during the mulligan decisions, I put infinite Cheatyfaces into play.  My opponent takes no non-required game actions, so they fail to catch me.  These were under my control at the beginning of my first turn, so I swing and attack for infinite on Turn 1 on the play.  Note that our Land/Goblin restriction only applies to the **deck**, and Cheatyface was never in my deck.  This is also what allowed me to have more than four of them without being a deck construction violation.

Comment: @Zerris Hah, good loophole. Mark Rosewater (Un Rules Manager) has said that Cheatyface is only able to be snuck in from your hand, but he seems to be the only person in the world who interprets the card that way.

Comment: Alternatively, for an even cheatier idea: T0 - Gemstone Mine, exiling anything.  T1.5 - R&D's Secret Lair > Akki > Skirk > Sac both for RR > Goblin Tutor (using R&D to ignore the errata to your own puzzle) rolling anything other than a 1 (now ignoring your errata about chance) thus searching our library - use this to put four Panglacial Wurms into play (ignoring Wurm's rules update about paying casting cost, and counting it as a goblin because goblin is in the flavor text, ignoring puzzle errata again), followed by casting Burst of Speed (with goblin in the flavor text again), swinging for 36.

Comment: @Zerris Now that's a bridge too far. "You have to pay the mana cost" isn't errata on Panglacial Wurm, it's on the card as written. Wurm says "you may play it", it's basic Magic rules that "you may play it" is different from "you may play it without paying its mana cost". I suppose you could define all changes to the comp rules as errata, but I doubt you could freecast the Wurm under Alpha rules. Heck, Alpha rules would probably choke and die the moment you tried to cast a card from your deck while resolving another spell.

Comment: I think it depends on the exact meaning of "play all cards as written", but I would agree with you.  R&D's secret lair doesn't look like it can do anything more broken than that - Kuldotha Rebirth is the only interesting spell we gain access to, and exploiting it requires also having a Great Furnace.  So I think it's just Cheatyface that's a problem... at least, for this puzzle.

Comment: Also, with Mons's Waiters, I can do a turn 1.5... but only if I get to have *five* of each card in my deck, rather than *four*.  It's that close: http://i.imgur.com/5GFsQds.png

Comment: Wait, got it! Grenzo to the rescue again.

Comment: @Zerris Jesus, turn 1. Before I post my next challenge, do you have an opinion on whether it's better to leave the scoring this open-ended, or should I put the challenge in terms of "It's possible to win/go infinite on turn X, find the solution that does so while using as few cards as possible?"

Comment: I'm definitely a fan of open ended scoring for all kinds of puzzles - often, somebody will find a solution that's better than the intended one, and I think that creativity should be rewarded.  Of course, that's also why the restrictions make it interesting - otherwise, the same cards tend to show up in every speed solution. For example, it looks like Grenzo is one of the best creatures in Legacy if your goal is to go infinite from no base with a stacked deck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it down to turn 1 on the draw if we allow Mons's Goblin Waiters!

**Turn 1 - infinite damage on the draw (16 cards used)**

> Turn 0:
>
>  Gemstone Caverns, exiling Mons's Goblin Raiders for irony (1 card "used")
>
>
>  Turn 1:
>
>  City of Traitors, tap both lands for 2R (2R, 2 cards)
>
>  Play Mons's Goblin Waiters for R, sacrifice both lands for R (2R, 3 cards)
>
>  Play Skirk Prospector for R, sacrifice Mons's Goblin Waiters for R (2R, 4 cards)
>
>  Play Mogg War Marshal for 1R, sacrifice it and both tokens for RRR (1RRR, 5 cards)
>
>  Play Mogg War Marshal for 1R, sacrifice it and both tokens for RRR (RRRRR, 6 cards)
>
>  Play Goblin Ringleader for RRRR, revealing Mogg War Marshal, Goblin Lackey, Goblin Bushwhacker, and Grenzo, Dungeon Warden, then sacrifice it for R (RR, 7 cards)
>
>  Play Mogg War Marshal for RR, sacrifice it and both tokens for RRR (RRR, 8 cards)
>
>  Play Goblin Lackey for R (RR, 9 cards)
>
>  Play Goblin Bushwhacker, Kicked, for RR (10 cards)
>
>  Attack with Goblin Lackey for 2 damage, put Grenzo, Dungeon Warden into play (11 cards)
>
>  Sacrifice Goblin Lackey and Goblin Bushwhacker for RR (RR, 11 cards)
>
>  Pay RR to Grenzo, revealing Siege-Gang Commander, put it into play, sacrifice it and all three tokens for RRRR (RRRR, 12 cards)
>
>  Pay RR to Grenzo, revealing Siege-Gang Commander, put it into play, sacrifice it and all three tokens for RRRR (RRRRRR, 13 cards)
>
>  Pay RR to Grenzo, revealing Goblin Sledder, put it into play, sacrifice it to give Grenzo +1/+1 (RRRR, 14 cards)
>
>  Pay RR to Grenzo, revealing Kiki-Jiki, Mirror Breaker, put it into play (RR, 15 cards)
>
>  Pay RR to Grenzo, revealing Lightning Crafter, put it into play, *but hold the ETB trigger on the stack...* (16 cards)
>
>  Tap Kiki-Jiki, targeting Lightning Crafter to create a token, champion Kiki-Jiki with the token, tap the token to deal your opponent 3 damage, then sacrifice the token for R, returning Kiki-Jiki to the battlefield untapped
>
>  Repeat the step above infinite times, dealing your opponent infinite damage!

Without Mons's, the best is turn two:

**Turn 2 (*pre-combat!*) - infinite damage on the play (12 cards used)**

> Turn 1:
>
>  [Geothermal Crevice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=23238) tapped (1 card used)
>
>
>  Turn 2:
>
>  Tap and sacrifice Geothermal Crevice, play [Frogtosser Banneret](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=152587) for BG (2 cards)
>
>  Mountain, play [Akki Rockspeaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=77919) for R, gaining R (R, 4 cards)
>
>  Play [Skirk Prospector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393985) for R (5 cards)
>
>  Sacrifice Akki Rockspeaker to gain R, play [Mogg War Marshal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393973) for R (6 cards)
>
>  Sacrifice Mogg War Marshal and both tokens for RRR (RRR, 6 cards)
>
>  Play [Mogg War Marshal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393973) for R (RR, 7 cards)
>
>  Sacrifice Mogg War Marshal and both tokens for RRR (RRRRR, 7 cards)
>
>  Play [Goblin Ringleader](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393963) for RRR, revealing Mogg War Marshal x2, Kiki-Jiki Mirror Breaker, Lightning Crafter (RR, 8 cards)
>
>  Play [Mogg War Marshal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393973), [Mogg War Marshal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393973) for RR (10 cards)
>
>  Sacrifice both Mogg War Marshals and all four tokens for RRRRRR (RRRRRR, 10 cards)
>
>  Sacrifice Goblin Ringleader for R (RRRRRRR, 10 cards)
>
>  Play [Kiki-Jiki, Mirror Breaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397698) for RRRR (RRR, 11 cards)
>
>  Play [Lightning Crafter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=152893) for RRR, *but hold the ETB trigger on the stack* (12 cards)
>
>  Tap Kiki-Jiki targeting Lightning Crafter to make a token, champion Kiki-Jiki with the token.  Tap the token to deal 3 damage to your opponent, then sacrifice the token to Skirk Prospector for R, returning Kiki-Jiki to the battlefield (untapped)
>
>  Repeat the above step infinite times, dealing infinite damage to your opponent!
>  (With the original Lightning Crafter trigger still on the stack)

As well as the most efficient kill:

**Turn 2 - infinite damage on the play (6 cards used)**

> Turn 1:
>
>  Mountain, [Goblin Lackey](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382959) (2 cards used)
>
>
>  Turn 2:
>
>  Tap Mountain for R, play [Skirk Prospector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393985) (3 cards)
>
>  Attack with Goblin Lackey for 1 damage, put [Kiki-Jiki, Mirror Breaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397698) into play (4 cards)
>
>  Play [Gaea's Cradle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=10422), Tap for GGG (GGG floating, 5 cards)
>
>  Sacrifice Goblin Lackey to Skirk Prospector for R (GGGR, 5 cards)
>
>  Play [Lightning Crafter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=152893) for GGGR, *but hold the ETB trigger on the stack* (6 cards)
>
>  Tap Kiki-Jiki targeting Lightning Crafter to make a token, champion Kiki-Jiki with the token.  Tap the token to deal 3 damage to your opponent, then sacrifice the token to Skirk Prospector for R, returning Kiki-Jiki to the battlefield (untapped)
>
>  Repeat the above step infinite times, dealing infinite damage to your opponent!
>  (With the original Lightning Crafter trigger still on the stack)

Optimizing for card efficiency another way:

**Turn 2 - infinite damage on the play (5 cards from hand)**

> I'm proud to have broken [Goatnapper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=142363), although the consequences may be tragic - after having proven that it facilitates a practically unbeatable turn two infinite combo deck, I am sure it will shortly be banned from Legacy, and we will all be poorer for the loss.

.

> Turn 1:
>
>  Mountain, [Goblin Lackey](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382959) (2 cards played)
>
>
>  Turn 2:
>
>  Attack with Goblin Lackey for 1 damage, put [Grenzo, Dungeon Warden](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382276) into play (3 cards)
>
>  Tap Mountain for R, play [Skirk Prospector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393985) (4 cards)
>
>  Play [Gaea's Cradle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=10422), Tap for GGG (GGG floating, 5 cards)
>
>  Pay GG to Grenzo, revealing [Siege-Gang Commander](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393982), put it into play, get three Goblin tokens
>
>  Sacrifice Siege-Gang Commander and all three tokens to Skirk Prospector for RRRR (GRRRR, 5 cards)
>
>  Sacrifice Goblin Lackey to Skirk Prospector for R (GRRRRR, 5 cards)
>
>  Pay GR to Grenzo, revealing [Amoeboid Changeling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=207921), put it into play
>
>  Pay RR to Grenzo, revealing [Goatnapper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=142363), put it into play targeting Amoeboid Changeling (a Goat, as well as a Goblin), untapping it, gaining control of it, and giving it haste
>
>  Pay RR to Grenzo, revealing [Kiki-Jiki, Mirror Breaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397698), put it into play
>
>  Tap Amoeboid Changeling (haste from Goatnapper) to give Kiki-Jiki all creature types until end of turn
>
>  Tap Kiki-Jiki, targeting Goatnapper, creating a token with haste.  Target Kiki-Jiki with the Goatnapper token trigger (Kiki-Jiki is currently a Goat as well as a Goblin), untap and gain control of Kiki-Jiki (as well as giving it more haste)
>
>  Repeat the above step infinite times for infinite Goatnapper tokens, leaving Kiki-Jiki untapped
>
>  Sacrifice your infinite Goatnapper tokens for infinite R from Skirk Prospector (Infinite R, 5 cards)
>
>  Pay RR to Grenzo, revealing [Goblin Sledder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393964), put it into play (Infinite R, 5 cards)
>
>  Sacrifice Skirk Prospector and Goblin Sledder, giving Grenzo +2/+2 until end of turn
>
>  Pay RR to Grenzo, revealing [Goblin Dynamo](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=42274), put it into play (Infinite R, 5 cards)
>
>  Tap Kiki-Jiki, targeting Goblin Dynamo, creating a token copy with haste
>
>  Tap and sacrifice the Goblin Dynamo token with X = infinite, dealing infinite damage to your opponent!

Comment: First thing I thought when I read the challenge: should've excluded changelings. Good job ;)

Comment: I left in changelings deliberately, although I didn't anticipate Goatnapper of all things. Good job to Zerris for finding a different infinite combo than the one I expected. There's room for a solution that uses less cards, so I'll wait a while to see if anyone comes up with it.

Comment: A clarification: When I say less cards, I'm counting "cards used" as described in the question, not merely cards played, although Grenzo is a brilliant way to keep your cards played low.

Comment: Well, there's an easy way to trade one card played for one card used, so I added that variant; I'll keep looking for a more efficient infinite combo.

Comment: Brilliant precombat solution. I found something similar when I tested the puzzle to make sure it had an interesting answer, but my answer used Goblin Warchief instead of Frogtosser, which made it less efficient. I have a few more of this type of very open-ended Magic challenge cooked up and tested, would you be interested in more of them?

Comment: I'd love them!  These open ended MTG puzzles are my favorite on Puzzling - it's tons of fun looking through the super obscure cards of MTG history on Gatherer trying to put together wacky combos that you'd never see in a real game.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't touched a Magic card for about 6 years, but I'll take a shot at setting a base. Choose to play.

> 1. Play a mountain and cast [Goblin Lackey](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382959)
> 2. Play a mountain and cast [Goblin Piledriver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398537); attack for 1, putting [Siege-Gang Commander](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393982) into the battlefield (with 3 1/1 goblin tokens).
> 3. Play a mountain and cast [Goblin Chieftain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=221201); attack for 23, 24 total damage, 7 cards played.

P.S. Wow. Magic got scary when I stopped playing, and most of my older cards appear to have been made obsolete by strictly better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming I can use any land I want, since it doesn't say I can only use Mountains or basics.

Choose to be on the play.

**Turn 1**: Mountain, [Goblin Lackey](http://magiccards.info/us/en/190.html)

**Turn 2**: [Ancient Tomb](http://magiccards.info/tp/en/305.html), [Goblin Rabblemaster](http://magiccards.info/m15/en/145.html). Attack with Lackey and the Rabblemaster token for 2. Put [Kiki-Jiki, Mirror Breaker](http://magiccards.info/chk/en/175.html) into play with the Lackey trigger.

On your opponent's end step, use Kiki-Jiki to make a copy of Goblin Rabblemaster (so it will survive to your next turn).

**Turn 3**: Mountain, [Goblin Chieftain](http://magiccards.info/m10/en/139.html). Use Kiki-Jiki to copy Goblin Rabblemaster. Go to combat, make 3 more tokens from Rabblemasters, attack your opponent with 6 2/2's and 3 11/3's for 45 damage.

47 total damage, 7 cards played.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, I deliberately left it open to any land you want.

Comment: Would be better if your last copy was another rabble master, you'd do 6x2+3x11 = 45

Comment: @DrunkWolf: I did the math and it's 40 damage either way. With another Rabblemaster, you'd have 4 tokens, the Lackey, and 3 Rabblemasters. that's 5x2 + 3x10 = 40.

Comment: @orp no, you're forgetting the chieftain, you still play it and attack with it (it has haste), you just copy the rabblemaster. so 6x2 + 3x11

Comment: @DrunkWolf: Oh, true, I forgot it had haste itself. I'll update.